# Using lapply() in renderUI() in Shiny Module

Tags: r, module, shiny, lapply

I am trying to convert a section of code into a Shiny Module, but my `renderPlot()` functions generated within an `lapply()` don't seem to be working. I have created a simple example below to demonstrate the issue.

*(Note: Here I'm using `renderText()` calls, but the same behavior applies.)*

app_normal.R:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Normal example"),
  uiOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      fluidRow(column(12,renderText(paste("Line", val))))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

app_module.R:

```
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("test"))
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      fluidRow(column(12,renderText(paste("Line", val))))
    })
  })
}

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"),
  myModuleUI("test_module")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, "test_module")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

All of the `div` elements are being created, but they just fail to contain the plots/text. How do I properly use the Shiny `renderText()` or `renderPlot()` functions within `renderUI()`/`lapply()` calls within a module?

Comment: Actually if I take out the `renderText()` in the module example and call  just `fluidRow(column(12,paste("Line", val)))` it seems to work just fine.

Comment: @MrFlick I see that removing `renderText()` allows the module to output text from the `lapply()`, but I am unable to implement this in my actual application where I'm using the `renderPlot()` function.

Comment: From what I understand the `renderUI()` should be outputting `plotOutput()`s, not calling `renderPlot()`. The `renderPlot()` should be the reactive value for those outputs. Maybe this link will help: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/HdCMHN8yjGM

Comment: Also look at the section called "RenderUI with Modules" [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html)

Answer (score 5):

It appears that the approach I was taking using the `renderText()` and `renderPlot()` functions directly in a `renderUI()` works fine in the normal case, i.e. when not operating within a Shiny Module. Shiny automatically calls the necessary `textOutput()` or `plotOutput()` to generate the HTML. Some how this automatic link is broken when you are performing the same operations within a Shiny Module. I suspect this is due to the mismatch between assigning and referencing items in the `output` list due to the introduction of the `ns()` call when assigning `outputId`s as is done manually in a call to `outputPlot()` or `outputText()`.

To successfully use `renderUI` within a Shiny Module, you need to separately call `textOutput()` and `renderText()`: `textOutput` in the `lapply()` in the `renderUI()`, and `renderText()` in an `lapply()` in an `observe()`. This allows us to introduce an `ns()` into the generation of the `outputId` for the `textOutput()` call.

Below I've included a refactoring of both `app_normal.R` and `app_module.R` that demonstrates the disentanglement of these two calls.

app_normal_observe.R:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Normal example"),
  uiOutput("test")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      fluidRow(column(12,textOutput(paste0("line_", val))))
    })
  })

  observe({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      output[[paste0("line_", val)]] <- renderText(paste("Line", val))
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

app_module_observe.R:

```
library(shiny)

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("test"))
}

myModule <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$test <- renderUI({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      fluidRow(column(12,textOutput(session$ns(paste0("line_", val)))))
    })
  })

  observe({
    lapply(1:3, function(val) {
      output[[paste0("line_", val)]] <- renderText(paste("Line", val))
    })
  })
}

ui <- fixedPage(
  h2("Module example"),
  myModuleUI("test_module")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  callModule(myModule, "test_module")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick for the suggestions above. The groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/HdCMHN8yjGM link demonstrated the use of an observe and the separation of the two calls (`renderText()` and `textOutput()`) that produced a working application.